# Is Ntru-Encrypt still secure in 2022

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, attack, ntru

I'm going to use NTRU as post-quantum public-key encryption algo in my project.
I've googled attacks on NTRU and found a lot of them
but since I'm new to NTRU and don't understand the math used, and could not conclude whether NTRU is still secure, if yes which parameter sets are secure?

For 256bit security, I found EES743EP1 and NIST NTRU-HRSS and NTRU-HPS
Wikipedia article says the latter one is secure against ***MOST*** attacks and says nothing about others.

My current library supports EES1087EP2 ,EES1171EP1,EES1499EP1 ,EES743EP1
are they secure? or I should switch to NTRU-HRSS or I'm better not to use NTRU?
(i don't care about speed and prefer  security over performance )

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wait for the finalization of the NIST PQC?

Comment: Normally I would say that if it is a final candidate for the NIST PQC that it would be considered secure, however with the current state I might get hammered into submission by Bernstein, as he certainly expressed doubts about the security of the CRYSTALS submissions (Kyber and Dilithium)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes my question only concerns attacks published/known till now,as far as I know NTRU is in the market for decades so current research doe it should be more reliable than new algo proposed

Comment: @kelalaka ok thanks, do you know if EES743EP1 is secure from attacks published till now? (as said in question Wikipedia only talks about NIST NTRU-HRSS)

Comment: How do you define "secure from attacks"? Bringing the security below the minimum security level decided by NIST? Bringing the security low enough that attacks are practical? An improvement in any attack at all? None of the supported algorithms you mentioned are _fatally_ broken, at least.

Comment: @forest sorry i should have told clearly , I mean security blow minimum level (~112/128bit)

Comment: @morthy I'm not writing an answer right now because I'm not completely sure, but I'm _pretty_ sure that no serious attacks exist against the listed parameters. Relevant: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88567/54184